# How do I print matches from a regex given a string value in Python?

Tags: python, regex, computer-science

I have the string "/browse/advanced-computer-science-modules?title=machine-learning"** in Python. I want to print the string in between the second `"/"` and the `"?"`, which is `"advanced-computer-science-modules"`.

I've created a regular expression that is as follows `^([a-z]*[\-]*[a-z])*?$` but it prints nothing when I run the `.findall()` function from the re module.

I created my own regex and imported the `re` module in python. Below is a snippet of my code that returned nothing.

```
regex = re.compile(r'^([a-z]*[\-]*[a-z])*?$')
str = '/browse/advanced-computer-science-modules?title=machine-learning'
print(regex.findall(str))
```

Comment: FWIW, the regex doesn't work because it's simply wrong and doesn't match your string. `^` (the start of the string) isn't followed by `[a-z]`…

Answer (score 1):

Since this appears to be a URL, I'd suggest you use [URL-parsing tools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit) instead:

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlsplit
>>> url = '/browse/advanced-computer-science-modules?title=machine-learning'
>>> s = urlsplit(url)
SplitResult(scheme='', netloc='', path='/browse/advanced-computer-science-modules', query='title=machine-learning', fragment='')
>>> s.path
'/browse/advanced-computer-science-modules'
>>> s.path.split('/')[-1]
'advanced-computer-science-modules'
```

Answer (score 0):

The regex is as follows:

```
\/[a-zA-Z\-]+\?
```

Then you catch the substring:

```
regex.findall(str)[1:len(str) - 1]
```

Very specific to this problem, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use `split` method of a `string`:

```
str = '/browse/advanced-computer-science-modules?title=machine-learning'
result = str.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]

print(result)
#advanced-computer-science-modules
```